# Check for unique numbers and extract index

Tags: python

I have a list of floats:

```
x = [1.69,1.69,2.36,2.63,2.63,3.00,3.00]
```

Finally I try to get a list with all equal numbers:

```
y = [1.69,1.69,2.63,2.63,3.00,3.00]
```

and the indices of unique numbers:

```
 z = [2]
```

Comment: I think the Git tag might be inappropriate here.  What language are you using?

Comment: What is the question here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've removed it and replaced it with Python (which they mentioned in the original copy)

Comment: You are asking here two questions. 1) How do i get the indices of all unique numbers
2) How do i remove unique numbers. The way you asked the question makes it sound like rocket science..

Comment: I am sorry for discomposure. Yes I want to remove all unique numbers, but also a list of their indices.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to create a dict with the count for each unique value in the list:

```
>>> import collections
>>> x = [1.69,1.69,2.36,2.63,2.63,3.00,3.00]
>>> c = collections.Counter(x)
>>> c
Counter({1.69: 2, 3.0: 2, 2.63: 2, 2.36: 1})
```

Then you can use some simple list comprehensions to get the unique and non-unique elements and/or their indices:

```
>>> [e for e in x if c[e] > 1]
[1.69, 1.69, 2.63, 2.63, 3.0, 3.0]
>>> [i for i, e in enumerate(x) if c[e] == 1]
[2]
```